how to do Swap Sol to different coins via TypeScript?
I'm currently working on a project where I need to swap Solana (SOL) for other cryptocurrencies programmatically using TypeScript. I understand the basics of working with blockchain technologies and have some experience with JavaScript and TypeScript. However, this is my first time trying to interact with Solana's blockchain in such a direct way.
I've been looking into Solana's web3.js library, as it seems to be the go-to solution for interacting with the Solana blockchain using JavaScript/TypeScript. Still, I'm not entirely sure about the best practices for executing swaps directly from SOL to other tokens. Does anyone have experience with this? Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on:
Connecting to the Solana network and setting up a wallet programmatically using TypeScript.
Finding a reliable and secure way to perform the swap. Are there specific decentralized exchanges (DEXs) or platforms on Solana that are recommended for this?
Any examples or tutorials that explain the process step by step would be incredibly helpful.
I would greatly appreciate any advice or pointers you can share. Even links to relevant documentation or code samples would be a huge help.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
